# Create dynamic library with dependecies

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dylib

I'm a web developer and has very poor knowledges in C++ compiler.

I have an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app and use [libmtp](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/) for it. I want to include libmtp to my project to avoid situation if libmpt is not installed on machine.

I call libmtp function from nodejs wrapper:

```
...
var mtp = new ffi.Library(pathToSrc + '/libmtp.9.dylib', {
...
```

libmtp depends on libusb, so if libusb is not installed on computer I get an error

> Error: Dynamic Linking Error: dlopen(/Users/username/Projects/projectname/build/projectname-darwin-x64/projectname.app/Contents/Resources/app/libmtp.9.dylib, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib

So the question is **How I can connect libmtp with libusb**

I can think about 2 ways:

1. Recompile libmtp with dependecy to libusb (How to do this is an open issue for me)
2. Set path to libusb.dylib for libmtp.dylib (This is an open issue for me too)

Thanks for any answers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can put libusb in your bundle and then change the search path for it with lib-name-tool. lib-name-tool lets you change the search for the lib so that it will look inside your bundle instead of /usr/local/lib. That way no local copy need be installed. This site shows how to do it with Qt applications. The principle is the same for you;

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html